# How to calculate the mean given one condition and multiple values in R

Tags: r, mean

I want to calculate the mean given a certain condition is met.
And have the code below.
How do you rewrite this to get R to do the mean for df$sta== B, C, etc. in one go and provide printed output in the Rstudio console.

```
 id<-c(1,2,3)
 val<-c(10,15,20)
 sta<-c("A","B","A")

 df<-data.frame(id,val,sta)

 mean(df$val[df$sta=="A"])
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `dplyr`:

```r
df %>%
  group_by(sta) %>%
  summarise(mean=mean(val))
```

gives

```r
# A tibble: 2 x 2
  sta    mean
  <fct> <dbl>
1 A        15
2 B        15
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option:

```
tapply(df$val, df$sta, mean)


 A  B 
15 15
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `aggregate` in `base R`

```
aggregate(val ~ sta, df, mean)
#  sta val
#1   A  15
#2   B  15
```